# Problema con implementación del MathView

Tags: android

Tengo problemas para implementar esta librería

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'MathView.aar (io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\E.F.O.M\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.kexanie.library\MathView\0.0.6\66c4930072521d2935696eb1049782d680099d3f\MathView-0.0.6.aar.
         > duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: Puedes usar MathView solo agregando la librería `'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'`

Comment: ¿Como estas declarando la dependencia?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

necesitas definir `jcenter()` dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` de tu proyecto, en el bloque `allprojects` > `repositories` , si usas `maven`, procura que `mavenCentral()` se encuentre antes de `jcenter()`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() //*Requerido para MathView
    }
}
```